# Apache2 WSGI Django - Directory access

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, apache2, wsgi

I have an Django(10.5) WSGI application running on Ubuntu(16.04). The application works completely except for one piece of functionality.

The functionality is located in the views.py file and it tries to get a list of file names in a directory but is unable too.

apache2 is running under the user www-data and the directory is owned by another user. I have tried to chown and chmod the directory so that it is owned by www-data but this didn't make a difference.

I have also added the following to the sites-available file:

```
<Directory /home/other_user/backup>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

NOTE: The functionality works if I run it in Django's dev server:

```
 python3 ./manage.py runserver 0:80
```

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering where you are trying to get the list of file names. Because Django project recognize that the directory where the manage.py located is the root directory. So The other directories outside of this root directory can't be recognized.(Due to BASE_DIR option in settings). It's nothing related with apache.

If you are trying to get the list of files in the directory which is inside root directory, the please check the permission.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The directory is outside of the root and it works fine with runserver when when logged in as the owner of the directory.